# authlogic - cause for unsuccessful session creation and no error messages (with formtastic)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authlogic, formtastic

I have 2 questions about authlogic:

1 - how to get cause of unsuccessful session creation (for example - not confirmed, blocked, wrong pass etc) to use it in app logic (route to another page for confimation, or re-enter pass etc)?

2 - question about integration formtastic and authlogic. How to show error messages on session creation , when login and pass is NOT provided. Everytime i submitting empty form - there are no any error message(but form.error_messages shows that you must enter login and pass), but if one of fields (login OR pass) provided - all works good.

Answer (score 2):

## 1:

If you follow the suggested pattern for the login url:

```
  def create
    @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
    if @user_session.save
      redirect_to your_url
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

The `@user_session` var will be available to your `new` template.  You can access any login errors with `@user_session.error_messages`.  I believe that returns formatted HTML, not an array.

**UPDATE**

According to [the docs](http://rdoc.info/rdoc/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/f2e95179acf87f11b44c7a58e6083cf84cddff27/Authlogic/Session/Validation.html), Authlogic errors behave exactly like active record, so, in order to map your controller logic, you would do something like

```
if @user_session.save
  # Normal flow
else
  if @user_session.errors.on(:password)
    # do something
  else
    # do something else
  end
end
```

Comment: yes, i know it. But i'd like to (for example) redirect user to different pages in dependency of confirmation/account_lock_status/validation_of_login-pass/etc .... but in your way - i can only work with error messages

Comment: You mean, depending on what the error the error is, you want the controller logic to change?